# guardar en carpeta publica laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como puedo guardar documentos en la carpeta public_html de mi servidor?

Estoy intentando guardar imágenes pero no lo consigo, en mi localhost funciona bien , adjunto mi código:

```
          if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $file = $request->file('img');
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path() .'\img\controles';        
            $file->move($path,$name);
          } 
           dd($path) =C:\xampp\htdocs\login\public\img\controles
```

la estructura de mi proyecto en local es así

- login

  - app
  - public

    - img

      - controles

en local no tengo problemas, me funciona todo bien, el problema lo tengo cuando lo migro al servidor, acá esta la estructura del proyecto

- login

  - app
  - public_html

    - css , js
    - img

      - controles

este es mi código (el mismo que más arriba, solo cambia el 'path')

```
          if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $file = $request->file('img');
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path() .'\img\controles';        
            $file->move($path,$name);
          } 
           dd($path) = /home/onelap/login/public/img/controles
```

entonces el problema se genera en el '$path', no puedo lograr a que me apunte a public_html/img/controles.
pd: he intentado con el método    *'$request->file('img')->store('public')'* pero solo me funciona en localhost y no en el servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las soluciones más sencillas es editar el archivo public/index.php para modificar la variable de la ruta public:

Después de la línea: `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

Agrega el siguiente código:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```